# how to embed a .mp4 video the url postfix with secret key

Tags: embed, videos

example URL:
http://ugcdl.video.gtimg.com/flv/185/77/i030481bzph.m701.mp4?vkey=B4D993A94B86BCBC49D3BE5479756DFFDBEA81EAA4D6D62BB54D086777A65DB6C58CF8C3DA483E61B0DF5835B393B5A6C604E4F3599173481BA62B31E4D8E89CAD51F4C013C74FC1275056E0B849675296B3A3E60C140D45

embed this url in content and use wp_video_shortcode function both not work.only show URL directly in frontend.

anyone can help me? 
thanks .

Answer (score 0):

You must have to open this URL in **iframe** to display as embed  format.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe width="420" height="345" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k">
</iframe>

</body>
```

For more about **IFRAME** Please visit this link 
https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_youtubeiframe

Comment: thank you.can you give me an example code or what the iframe code like?I am newer and english poor.thanks!

Comment: it works for youtube but ot work with my example URL.thank you.

Comment: Welcome Have fun!!!!